How to Grant SYSTEM_USER Privilege Using Terraform for MySQL Database?
I'm trying to automate the setup of a MySQL database using Terraform for my project hosted on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to execute a SQL script that requires the SYSTEM_USER privilege. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

Error running command
'mysql -h <IP_ADDRESS> -P 3306 -u root -p  < ./database.sql': exit status 1.
Output: mysql:
[Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 510: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SYSTEM_USER privilege(s) for this operation

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "mysql_instance" {
  name             = var.instance_name
  database_version = "MYSQL_8_0"
  region           = "us-central1"
  root_password    = var.password

  settings {
      disk_autoresize = "false"
      disk_size       = "10"
      disk_type       = "PD_SSD"
      tier            = "db-n1-standard-1"
      ip_configuration {
        ipv4_enabled = "true"
        dynamic "authorized_networks" {
          for_each = var.cloud_sql.authorized_networks
          iterator = network
          content {
            name  = "ip-${network.key}"
            value = network.value
          }
        }
      }
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  name     = "cloud_sql_db"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.mysql_instance.name

  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "mysql -h ${google_sql_database_instance.mysql_instance.public_ip_address} -P 3306 -u root -p${google_sql_database_instance.mysql_instance.root_password} ${google_sql_database.database.name} < ${var.sql_script}"
  }
}

resource "google_sql_user" "users" {
  name     = "root"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.mysql_instance.name
  host     = "%"
  password = google_sql_database_instance.mysql_instance.root_password
}


Access denied; you need the SYSTEM_USER privilege for this operation that is the error, the other is just a warning ... that google_sql_user does not have that, maybe that is set on the type: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_user#type

Yeah, But what I'm asking is how can i grant system user priviledge to a user via terraform
